# Maven project is not working after import

Tags: selenium, maven, automation, testng, rest-assured

[image]I have imported the Maven project(RestAssured API) and did the Maven--> Update project. But when I run this I don't see the TestNG option in Run as. Also, Dependency is not updated because of code level. throwing me a warning as shown in the picture.
#Note: The same project was working fine before because my laptop is corrupted I reinstalled everything after that it's not working.

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Please show full pom file, Maven version, JDK version, and of course the real log output ...and describe what it mean "is not working"...

Comment: Try Maven -> Update -> Select "Force updates" and do

Comment: @khmarbaise JDK 1.8

Comment: @NandanA tried that but same as you can see in the snapshot dependencies are not loading.

Comment: Go to project (fromt the top menu)first and clean it and then again go the project -> maven and force update, this should ideally work.

Comment: @cruisepandey I think the dependencies are loaded but he never used "RestAssured".

Comment: @NandanA: he hasn't used the rest assured one, however if you scroll down in that snapshot, you'd see that he has one error as well which says 'could not find or load class file '

Comment: @cruisepandey yes, that's a different issue. Based on his ask I assumed dependencies are not downloaded in .m2 folder.

Comment: @cruisepandey U mean to say Maven clean - right click on a project?

Comment: When I right-click and select Run as I don't see TestNg option

Comment: @Ash28: No not maven clean, do this `Go to project (fromt the top menu)first and clean it`

Comment: @cruisepandey Clean and force update done but still same issue. I am not getting right click Runas TestNg option?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can you try checking the Build Path and check the Jre is Configured properly or not.

And try Running the Java main class i.e Run the BasicFirst class directly instead of running the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go to `Project > Properties > Libraries > [Add Library] > TestNG > Finish.`

This might fix your problem.